# Actionscript read XML and write on List write

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, list

I'm trying to read a XML file and output the values, but i'm getting a `1120: Access of undefined property URLRequest.` error. Any ideas?
Here's my code:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    public function Main()
    {

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);

        function loadXML(e:Event):void
        {
            var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
            trace(xml);
        }

        loader.load(new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1:8090/NewProj/index.php?tipo=get"));
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loader.load(new URLRequest.data("http://127.0.0.1:8090/NewProj/index.php?tipo=get"));` That looks weird. It should be

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1:8090/NewProj/index.php?tipo=get"));
```

EDIT:
You also need to import the relevant packages eg

```
import flash.net.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already discovered the typo you have in the last line of the code above `new URLRequest.data(...` It should be `new URLRequest(...`

Comment: A missing import then - `import flash.net.URLRequest;` Please check if you have this line in your file!